# some problem when responsive a html css file, the item file display irregularly and when responsive, item file does not display in full screen

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I made a very simple html css file and here is my code

https://github.com/anhbui2904/example21

And I have some questions, the first problem is, why at full screen, the box is in the middle of the screen, not at the left hand, even if I use at the .grid.wide as `justify-content: left;`?

My second problem is, why all 5 boxes at the right are not in the same line with the left box?

My third problem is, why when I change the code

```
.row {
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}
```

to

```
.row {
    margin-left: -6px;
    margin-right: -6px;
}
```

the distance between columns does not decrease?

Could you please help me with those problems? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: please type the section of your code that requires assistance. Refrain from posting links to your code.

Comment: Your codesanbox example seems no longer working?

Comment: @konekoya sorry for my mistake, I have just edit my link, could you please help me for my problem ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your codesandbox isn't editable. about your second problem, you must remove flex-wrap: wrap; If you want all boxes to be in the same line.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi thank you for your comment, I change to upload my code to github, so hope that U can see my code to help me. By the way, when I remove flex-wrap: wrap, it still display the same problem ? Could you please see for me again for this problem ?

Comment: You're welcome. Is the code of grid.css important for this work? It is very long and confusing! In my editor, when I remove flex-wrap: wrap; from '.row', without using CSS of 'grid.css', all boxes are placed in the same line (no wrapped) and the left side. But when I use grid.css, boxes are placed in the center.

Comment: @NguyenCuc I read your question about 5 times, I have no idea what you're asking.
Instead of telling the problem, tell us what you want the result to be